# Swift weakSelf in closure syntax

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have this code to get JSON:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, worlds).responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
        println(JSON)
        //weakSelf.serverList = JSON
    }
```

How to declare weakSelf here? I know it should be unowned in my case, but I can't find correct syntax for this. When I try use [unowned self].serverList instead of the commented line, the compiler shows me error "use of unresolved identifier 'unowned'". 
I also tried to declare constant before block like this:

```
unowned let uSelf = self
```

It works like a charm, but I want to understand how to use [unowned self] in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the capture list. The correct syntax is:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, worlds).responseJSON { [unowned self] (request, response, JSON, error) in
    println(JSON)
    self.serverList = JSON
}
```

However take a note that you are not creating retain cycle here, so you do not have to use `weak` or `unowned` self here. Good article on this topic: http://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/05/demystifying-retain-cycles-in-arc/

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a weak self reference by putting `[weak self]` before your closure parameters.

You can see the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57)