# Do I need [unowned self] in AlamoFire, or is it already taken care of?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
        let parameters = [
            "access_token": access_token,
        ]
        self.alamoFireManager!.request(.POST, CONSTANTS.APIEndpoint+"/auth", parameters: parameters).responseJSON { [unowned self]
            response in
            self.startWorking()
        }
```

Do I need unowned self inside the closure, or is it already taken care of by the library?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Alamofire.request` instead of `self.alamoFireManager` and you are good to go without capturing self. If you really need to use `self.alamoFireManager`, as @Tapani mentioned, since `alamoFireManager` is a property of self, you need to capture self and use [weak self] in the closure

I was looking for the same answer you were looking for. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207667/1120126) answer. It mentions about an article about retain cycles. I think you don't need to capture self here.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is a good one, and the simple answer is that no, you do not need to use `[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` in your response handlers to make Alamofire work properly. The choice is 100% up to you, the caller, whether you have created your own `SessionManager` as in this example, or whether you are using the `Alamofire.request` APIs which leverage the `SessionManager` singleton.

### Alamofire Internals

The memory management of the request itself is all managed internally in Alamofire leveraging GCD queues. If you make a request, that request will complete and call the completion handler as long as the `SessionManager` you made the request on stays in memory. The singleton `SessionManager` obviously will not be released from memory.

> **If you created your own `SessionManager`, make sure you don't release it before your request completes.**

### Additional Thoughts

The question here shouldn't really be so much about whether you need to use unowned or weak self for Alamofire's sake, but for your own. Do you to guarantee that the request completes successfully? If yes, then you need to capture self here and avoid weak and unowned self to ensure the request completes. For example, let's say `self` in this example is a `Network` class. If you deallocate your `Network` class while a request is in flight, that will also deallocate your custom `alamoFireManager` instance which will invalidate the underlying `URLSession` which will in turn cancel your request. Generally, you don't want this to happen and you'd want to capture self inside the response handler to ensure it won't get shut down pre-maturely.

Answer (score 0):

`alamoFireManager` is a property of `self` so if it saves the closure to a property and you capture `self` then there is a retain cycle. If you are not sure you should always use `weak self`. That does no harm, but not using it when needed may cause a lot of trouble. Also, `unowned self` is dangerous because it is not optional. If it's `nil` and you try to use it your app crashes. You should use `weak self` instead.

Comment: Check out http://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/05/demystifying-retain-cycles-in-arc/ and search for "This is not a good practice"

Comment: But you are right about `alamoFireManager` being a propert of self

Comment: I don't completely agree with that blog post. If the object does not exist anymore after a long network request then there either is a bug in the code or it's just good that the object does not exist anymore. What I do agree, is that the let strongSelf = self syntax is ugly and defeats the whole purpose of the closures. Closures should automatically have invisible [weak self] and make the weak reference strong when the closure is called. If someone wants a different behaviour then they could specify [strong self] or [unowned self].

Comment: I may agree with you "it's just good that the object does not exist anymore". But since your proposal isn't implemented, the blog post is more valid. At least I think this way :)

Comment: Many things in the closure can be done using self?.something instead of strongSelf.something. That way the syntax is not as ugly. Of course with e.g. dispatch functions or something like UIView's animate functions there is no reason to use weak self just for sure. If the coder is not very experienced it's much better to have ugly code than make retain cycle bugs.

Comment: I think your proposal is the better solution. Doesn't make you use an ugly syntax and safer